# Is it possible to control my CPU frequency?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, cpu, temperature

My laptop's CPU Type is:

> Mobile AMD Turion 64 ML-30, 1600 MHz (8 x 200)

I was wondering how to find out if its CPU frequency is controllable?

What softwares or other ways can control my CPU frequency? My OSes are Windows XP and Ubuntu.

Can I control CPU frequency so that the CPU temperature can be controlled not to exceed some temperature?

Thanks and regards!

---

More information:

My laptop is Acer Aspire 5000. Its motherboard is reported by [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) as:

> Manufacturer: Acer, Inc.
>   Model:    Lugano M
>   Version:  Not Applicable
>   Chipset Vendor:   SiS
>   Chipset Model:    760GX
>   Chipset Revision: 03
>   Southbridge Vendor:   SiS
>   Southbridge Model:    LPC Bridge
>   Southbridge Revision: 25
>     BIOS
>         Brand:  Acer
>         Version:    3A19
>         Date:   05/17/05

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be possible to change the CPU frequency. In XP, something like [SpeedSwitchXP](http://www.diefer.de/speedswitchxp/) might work. I haven't tried it myself so try it at your own risk. XP regulates the cpu frequency behind the scenes based on the power scheme selected as far as I know.

In Ubuntu, You can right click an empty space on one of the panel's (aka task-bar) and click "Add to Panel..." From there you get a list of items that you can add to the panel. The one you want to add is the "CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor". If CPU frequency scaling is supported, you should be able to left click it and select your frequency options.

Unfortunately I don't know how to change the frequency based on heat. Hopefully someone else can help you with that. I would expect it might be possible with a script of some sort.

If you are having overheating issues, try blowing any dust out with compressed air and make sure all the fans are able to spin.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you need to enable a group of thermal features for processor (in kernel, sometimes "ubuntishly" enabled by default), a group of 'cpufreq' users, and set a default 'governor' - how the temp is changed..

/opt/cpu_off

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in 0 1 2 3
do
        echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_governor
        cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
done
```

/opt/cpu_on

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in 0 1 2 3
do
        echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_governor
        cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
done
```

Those are scripts for setting a 4-core CPU.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a cpu temperature applet in the default list of panel applets, but there are applets to control cpu temperature in the repositories. I use one called cputemp or something along those lines, and I have both that and the cpu frequency scaling one installed on my panel as my cpu seems to overheat pretty easily (I think my fans may be defective ... or the laptop wasn't that well designed in general ... it's had overheating problems since the beginning, despite having it on a cooler).

Both applets have options for warnings etc. I haven't found a nice way to change the cpu frequency automatically depending on temperature ... but what I have done is make the system play a sound whenever the cpu temp exceeds 85 degrees ... at which point I remember I'm doing something CPU intensive (usually involving flash ... grrr), and I scale the CPU frequency down temporarily.